Steel tubing size question for building a giant swing
a customer has asked me to build a giant swing that will be suspended between two trees in a forest near their home. The swing will need to be 12 feet wide and could end up supporting eight or nine people at one time. I want to build a metal subframe for this so I can keep it as light as possible as wood members would have to be very large and heavy. My question is, what size steel tubing would I need to use? I would want the 12 foot span to horizontally support eight or nine people of average weight (150-175 lbs) without much flex in the center. I plan to make the subframe under the seat a large rectangle measuring approximately 144”x17”. The entire swing would be suspended at each end by chain.
Any advice would be appreciated
Thank you
J

hire a structural engineer ... you are risking lawsuits if you don't

Don't design on average, design on max plus tolerance - stupidity knows no limits. Drunk students trying to see how many they can get on it...
